# Is any data field become "Static" without declaring it explicitly?

Tags: java

I have declared private data field without "static" modifier but when i called the data field from a method. compiler said a "static reference to the non-static method" only for one data filed "annualInterestRate" and other's seem okay.

I also declared other data with same manner but they have no problem. but in case of "annualInterestRate" data field it's give error.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Account {
    private int id;
    private double balance;
    private double annualInterestRate;
    private java.util.Date dateCreated;
    public Account() {

    }
    public Account(int id, double balance, double interestRate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.annualInterestRate = interestRate;
        dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
    public void setInterestRate(double annualInterestRate) {
        this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
    }
    public double getInterestRate() {
        return annualInterestRate;
    }
    public java.util.Date getDate(){
        return dateCreated;
    }
    public double getMonthlyInterestRate() {
    double  monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/12.0;
        return monthlyInterestRate;
    }
    public double getmonthlyInterest() {
        double monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/12.0;
        return monthlyInterestRate*balance;
    }
    public void withdraw(double balance) {
        this.balance-=balance;
    }
    public void deposit(double balance) {
        this.balance+=balance;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int id;
        double balance,interestRate,mir;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        id = in.nextInt();
        balance = in.nextDouble();
        interestRate = in.nextDouble();
        Account Person = new Account(id, balance, interestRate);
        Person.withdraw(2500.0);
        Person.deposit(3000.0);
        mir = getmonthlyInterest();
        System.out.println(balance + " " + mir + " " + dateCreated);

    }

}
```

expected to run smoothly

Comment: Did you mean to write  `this.annualInterestRate` instead of `annualInterestRate.this` ? Also I suspect you may have some `Person` class somewhere, conflicting with your variable called `Person` (note that by convention, variable names should start with a lower-case character, and possibly be relevant with the object they represent).

Comment: All your "this" usage is wrong in your code. Should be `this.<instance variable>`

Comment: Side note: you really shouldn't use `Date`, it's obsolete. Instead, use the classes from the `java.time` package.

Comment: Also, you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names always start with lowercase. Your variable `Person` should be `person`.

Comment: i'm new java. however, i did the corrections still have same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting slightly your main method to use an instance of your Account class :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int id;
        double balance,interestRate,mir;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        id = in.nextInt();
        balance = in.nextDouble();
        interestRate = in.nextDouble();
        Account myPerson = new Account(id, balance, interestRate);
        myPerson.withdraw(2500.0);
        myPerson.deposit(3000.0);
        mir = myPerson.getmonthlyInterest();
        System.out.println(balance + " " + mir + " " + myPerson.getDate());

    }
```